# How to handle error code with message in react

Tags: reactjs

In angular we have something like mport {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";

so when we make a post call using http and Rxjs,like below code..we have something called ErrorEvent.

```
private runBuild(jobName: string, payload: string) {
        return this.http.post(this.jenkinsURLs.runJobUrl(jobName), "json=" + encodeURIComponent(payload), httpOptions)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    };

    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        let errorMessage: string = '';
        ***if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            errorMessage = 'An error occurred: ' + error.error.message;
        } else {
            errorMessage = `Jenkins returned code ${error.status}, body was: ${error.message}`;
        }***
        return throwError(errorMessage);
    };
```

but in react, if I want to have different messages for different error codes, I have to do it manually because we don't have something like ErrorEvent.

COuld you please suggest any generic way to have some sort of ErrorEvent so that I can assign different message by validating the instanceOf operator in react

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap < App /> (or at another relevant place to wrap just once) with < ErrorBoundary > that will be trigger to do something at componentDidCatch lifeCycle. {((error, errorInfo)} params at this lifeCycle can be the handlers of the fit error that suppose to be shown - https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html